# Syntax error: “[” unexpected

Tags: php

The php code displaying unexpected syntax error [ on line number 1
I am not sure what is the issue.

```
   $shipping_array = [ "AL" => ["a","c","b"],
    "AZ" => ["b","c","a"],
    "AR" => ["a","c","b"],
    "WI" => ["c","a","b"] ];
```

Comment: shorthand array declaration is for PHP 5.4 above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a short array declaration for that you have to use PHP 5.4 or higher.

Try this under PHP 5.4:

```
 $shipping_array = array(
    "AL" => array("a","c","b"),
    "AZ" => array("b","c","a"),
    "AR" => array("a","c","b"),
    "WI" => array("c","a","b") 
 );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$shipping_array = array(
                    "AL" => array("a","c","b"),
                    "AZ" => array("b","c","a"),
                    "AR" => array("a","c","b"),
                    "WI" => array("c","a","b")
                );
```

If your using `PHP 5.4` or higher you can use this:

```
$shipping_array = [
        "AL" => ["a","c","b"],
        "AZ" => ["b","c","a"],
        "AR" => ["a","c","b"],
        "WI" => ["c","a","b"]
    ];
```

For more information take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score -2):

problem in your syntax you must try this :

```
$shipping_array = array( "AL" => array("a","c","b"),
                         "AZ" => array("b","c","a"),
                         "AR" => array("a","c","b"),
                          "WI" => array("c","a","b")
                        );
```

Comment: The syntax is not the problem! It's the PHP version